# files in HDFS inaccessible every time when I restart the cluster?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I have just configured a clone hadoop version 2.7.3, I load my data sizes from 1 g up to 20 go and I use this data (can manipulate them ...) but when I restart the cluster this data does not Will not be accecible.
I will have this message:
WARNING : There are about xx missing blocks. Please check the log or run fsck, it means that some blocks in your HDFS installation do not have a single replica on any of the live DataNodes.
here is the hdfs-site.xml:

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
        <value>file:///home/hduser/hadoop-2.7.3/namenode</value>
        <description>NameNode directory for namespace and transaction logs storage.</description>
    </property>
   <property>
    <name>dfs.safemode.threshold.pct</name>
    <value>0</value>
   </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.replication</name>
        <value>1</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.permissions</name>
        <value>false</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.datanode.use.datanode.hostname</name>
        <value>false</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.namenode.datanode.registration.ip-hostname-check</name>
        <value>false</value>
    </property>
    <property>
         <name>dfs.namenode.http-address</name>
         <value>node1:50070</value>
         <description>Your NameNode hostname for http access.</description>
    </property>
    <property>
         <name>dfs.namenode.secondary.http-address</name>
         <value>node1:50090</value>
         <description>Your Secondary NameNode hostname for http access.</description>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

Comment: You are running with no replication. That means that if any DataNode goes down, there will be corrupt files (missing blocks). Is this a test config? Are you running multiple DataNodes?

Comment: yes i just use for multiple dataNodes and i just set the replication  parametres to 3 and it does not work
, and whene i restart my cluster this data its not accessible.

Comment: You may also want to configure the safemode.threshold to something higher (default is 0.99). My guess is during the restart, the DataNodes have not checked in with NameNode and since you have safemode disabled, you're getting missing block errors.

Comment: i thank you for your suggestion, you can give me an value to set in safe mode parameter

Comment: I'd try the default (0.99)

Comment: @inoubli Are the configurations same on Datanodes as the one posted here?

Comment: @franklinsijo yes i keep same configurations in all datanodes

Comment: @jeff i just set safemode value to 0.99 but when i open my hdfs browser i get this message :Zero blocklocations for /1go. Name node is in safe mode. The reported blocks 0 needs additional 37 blocks to reach the threshold 0,9900 of total blocks 37. The number of live datanodes 12 has reached the minimum number 0. Safe mode will be turned off automatically once the thresholds have been reached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default value of the property `dfs.datanode.data.dir` is `${hadoop.tmp.dir}/dfs/data` and **`hadoop.tmp.dir`** is `/tmp` which gets cleaned up on reboot and thus all your blocks are lost.

You have to add this property to the `hdfs-site.xml` in all the datanodes,

```
<property>
    <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
    <value>file:///home/hduser/hadoop-2.7.3/datanode</value>
</property>
```